# How to run gulp tasks in parallel in gulp 3.9.1?

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
gulp.task('a', function (cb) {
  //... cb() 
})

gulp.task('b', function (cb) {
  //... cb() 
})
```

I have two tasks, they take too match time, the question is how to run them simultaneously in order to save time?

Gulp version - 3.9.1

Comment: this is new beta version, we use 3.9.1

Comment: Your tasks probably already run in parallel. If you call both tasks from the command line with `gulp a b` they will run in parallel.